# Change Image Button in Adapter Listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Can Anyone help me. Where is my fault?
I have an adapter listview is:

```
db = Database.getReadableDatabase();
            String queryString = "SELECT * from TBL_CHECKIN WHERE FLAG='1' and NOCUST='" + ListViewCallplan.get(position).gettxid() + "'";
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);
            if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                System.out.println("ok1");
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                holder.image .setImageResource(R.mipmap.cekin);
                holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent logtent = new Intent(context, Cls_Checkin.class);
                            logtent.putExtra("custcode", ListViewCallplan.get(position).gettxid());
                            context.startActivity(logtent);
                        }
                    });
    //                notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("okcekot");
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    holder.image .setImageResource(R.mipmap.cekout);
                    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent logtent = new Intent(context, Cls_Checkout.class);
                            context.startActivity(logtent);
                        }
                    });
    //                notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

I want to change image the button with that condition, but when me open again it's not do nothing. Stay in same display. The image in button always show checkin for the example.